# Transaction Isolation level Massive number of Writes

Tags: sql, transactions, isolation-level

I may be talking nonsense but:

Which isolation level is "best" for 
lots of Threads running on lots of connections, executing lots of updates and writes using transactions?
Or isolationlevels are only for reads?

--EDIT
DBMS ... InnoDB mysql... 
best.. well what i want is to run parallel transactions of writes/updates, and if for example we have two updates on the same Column, i do not whant to get concurrency problems...

so parallel writes/updates, which all run with locking on the database
--EDIT
After couple of readings came to this conclusion

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-lock-modes.html

So Update takes row lock, not a shared lock, so there should be no problems when updating.
But one must check beforehand which thread comes to the connections that locks..
So there should be no concurent updates to the databse on the same row...
so

NO:

```
t1 - T1: update (id 1) 
t2 - T2: update (id 1)
```

One must care that two threads do not come to update the same row... but from database point of view, as long it is InnoDB and has lowest level of Isolation READ_UNCOMMITED, there should not be a problem
I will come with an update after couple of moths :D

Comment: Please define "best" and give more details about your DBMS.

Comment: i have edited the question, if you have more questions, do not hesitate..

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb: the higher your isolation leven (higher meaning: more isolation) the more locks and overhead you get. So if you want to go as fast and as parallel as possible you want no isolation at all.

Of course this might destroy your business logic, so I think there really is no alternative to looking at all the isolation levels available and checking them against your requirements.

Comment: hm.. I was thinking more for REPEATABLE READ.... But what you are bascialy saying is that if I use NONE, and care in application not to update the same item twice, i should not get problems?

Comment: Almost. If you don't care at all if and when you see or don't see parts of what other sessions do, you SHOULD be fine.

Comment: One more question: If two transactions from two separate threads without Isolation, writing on the same table, but different columns (save id 2) (update id 1), will this lead to problems?

Comment: Sorry can't really heelp on that level of detail. You need some detailed knowledge of the actual rdbms used.

Comment: @Darwly - "care in application not to update the same item twice" - you mean, you're going to re-implement the locking at a higher level, and the locking code is probably not going to be as thoroughly tested as that which exists inside the database?

Comment: In some cases this can be done without locks, but just based on the algorithm the application uses.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever well yea.. I would not have a real locking mechanism at the database level, only lock on a ROW on Update. InnoDB has this implemented already. I do not care about readings.. so if i do not have an update on the same ROW, there will not be any racing conditions, because The threads are already sycnronized beforehand in app. am i clearer? I am using this solution for my app http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518549/hibernate-c3p0-threadpoolexecutor-connection-pooling-am-i-doing-it-right/9518679#comment12056692_9518679